# How do I use other elements fom one list?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
data = [['2001', '20', '0', '0', '10', '0', '15', '0'],
        ['2004', '15', '0', '9.5', '13', '10', '18', '30']]
```

My work is to use items of sublists in this list of lists:

```
def FinalMark(studentNum):
    if studentNum in data:
```

I don't know what to do next.  Let's say if 2001 is the first item of a sublist,  I want to  know  how to use others items  of  this sublist.

Comment: Use a dict instead.

Comment: Loop through the list, and test if the first element of the sub-list is `studentNum`.

Comment: can u guys show me example?

Comment: If you want to look up data by year, then make the year a key in a dictionary, as Natecat suggested. And do not store numbers as strings, either: `data = {2001 : [20, 0, 0, 10, 0, 15, 0], 2004 : [15, 0, 9.5, 13, 10, 18, 30]}`

Comment: no the data part i cant change..

Comment: You probably should read a nested list tutorial before attempting an exercise like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to do it by storing the data as a dictionary. But with what you have, you can loop through `data`:

```
def FinalMark(studentNum):
    for marks in data:
        if marks[0] == studentNum:
            return sum([float(i) for i in marks[1:]])
```

`marks[1:]` is a slice of `marks` that skips the first element (the student number).

Comment: `int(i)` will not work as one of the values is `'9.5'`. Should you not use `float` instead?

Comment: thanks. Also how do i use the individual element? Like in the 2001 one i want to use 20, 0, then all of them individually to do another calculations?

Comment: The function should do something if the student is not found. IMHO.

Comment: @David.Lin You can access specific elements with `marks[1]`, `marks[2]`, etc. This is basic Python syntax, what's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I know this, trust me.

Comment: @DYZ Sorry, I meant to send it to the OP, auto-complete picked you.